# Arch Linux iMX6 capacitive touch LCD panel

Tags: embedded, touch-screen, arch-arm

I want to create an embedded system with a 7 inch capacitive touch screen and am planning on using Arch Linux on a Varscite made Freescale iMX6 quad based SOM development kit for this purpose. What I am struggling to find info on is how I should approach getting Arch Linux ARM running on a new board, as far as I can determine this should not be to hard as there is already a generic release for the iMX6 but I apparently still have to do something to get it running on this specific board but I have no idea what it is and how I should go about doing it.

Another thing that I am struggling to figure out is how to deal with setting up Arch to display to an LCD panel like the FM-TPM070800480-01 from Fannal, how is this dealt with? Where do I need to configure timing for the display etc.?

The last thing I need to find out is how I would go about getting Arch to respond to the i2c touch events that capacitive panels generate?

Comment: Hello, did you ever get this working? I want to run a 7" lcd touch screen on arch linux. How did you get yours to work?